# Telnet issue on remote 8240

Tags: 18.04

We have two server one Centos 7 and another is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS both are is same network.

All the required ports are open on both the end. we are able to telnet CentOS 7 from Ubuntu 18.04 on port 8240. but not able get telnet connection from either side.

Telnet should be able to get viseversa on port 8240.

Kindly do the needful.

Comment: Is the telnetd server/daemon installed and configured on the Ubuntu server? What does `sudo apt install telnetd` say ?

Comment: Temporarily turn off `ufw` and see if that help.  Also run `sudo iptables -L` and look for anything that might be blocking that port.